# Is creating an email application possible with angular?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

Is **creating an email application possible with angular**?

I tried implementing [nodejs script](https://dev.to/mesadhan/manage-your-re-mail-using-imap-2p18) but it's not working due to using nodejs script inside angular ts file, giving me the following
**Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'imap'**

Any help or guide would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use modules which depend on Node.js features from a browser. The imap module depends on such a feature: it requires the ability to make raw network requests.

The block here is at a lower-level than Angular.

You could replace direct IMAP (and SMTP) access with a web service since browsers support HTTP and WebSockets.

Answer (score 0):

You can’t make IMAP/SMTP connections directly from the browser, but you could use something like [EmailEngine](https://emailengine.app/) as the backend for any email related actions.